# I am trying to connect my Android project to Firebase, real-time database but it always failed. Plase help me find what mistake is

Tags: android

2019-03-19 17:48:03.848 9496-9496/com.example.test_firebase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test_firebase, PID: 9496
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test_firebase/com.example.test_firebase.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.test_firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.test_firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:240)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:67)
        at com.example.test_firebase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context), as the error says.

Answer (score 0):

> "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process"

In this link is described how to setup your project with Firebase (Automatically from Android Studio and Manually). My recommendation is to do it Manually.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

If this is not your case, you only need to start method:

```
Firebase.init();
```

and

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Comment: I will try by following your instruction.